# I need help on ubuntu 9.10 crontab,

Tags: cron

I need to setup cron every 30 min to start and end Adobe AIR application which is not happening at present.
I am using following command.

*/30 * * * * /opt/myapp/myapp

can any one tell me what mistake I am making.

What I found was cron does not execute GUI app.
Only command lines are accepted jobs are accepted.

Please guide me what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Run it under [Xvfb](https://superuser.com/search?q=xvfb).